# How can I set multiple fields as primary key in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, composite-primary-key

I am trying to create a collection with 50+ fields. I understand that the purpose of the primary key is to uniquely identify a record. Since the primary key is the _id in MongoDB that gets created automatically, isn't it obvious that all my records including duplicate would go into my DB with unique _id for evert record? Tell me where I'm going wrong.Other articles and discussions are more confusing.

1. How to set any one/more of the other fields as a primary key? But I don't want the default _id as primary key.
2. In what way, compound indexes are different from compound/primary key?

Comment: you can set whatever value you want for `_id` while inserting document. If `_id` is not provided then mongodb creates default `_id` field

Comment: @Undefined_variable Could you please explain me with an example of setting a composite primary key.

Comment: You cannot declare composite primary key. Let's say you have 2 cloumns in RDMS as composite primary key, so while inserting records in mongodb your document structure wold be `{"_id":"A_B"}` where A and B are values of 2 columns respectively

Comment: @Undefined_variable How about `_id:{a:"foo",b:"bar"}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such notion as a primary key in MongoDB. Terminology matters. Not knowing the terminology is a sure sign someone hasn't read the docs or at least not carefully.

A document in a collection **must** have an `_id` field which **may** be and by default is an ObjectId. This field has an index on it which enforces a unique constraint, so there can not be any two documents with the same value or combination of values in the `_id` field. Which, by what you describe, presumably is what you want.

My suggestion is to reuse the default `_id` as often as you can. Additional indices are expensive (RAM-wise). You have two options here: either use a different single value as `_id` or use multiple values, if the cardinality of the single field isn't enough.

Let us assume you want a clickstream per user recorded. Obviously, you need to have the unique user. But that would not be enough, since a user only could only have one entry. But since you need a timestamp fo each click anyway, you move it to the `_id` field:

```
{
  _id:{
    user: "some user",
    ts: new ISODate()
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Well, that did answered my question. Thanks. Can I change the _id to what you have suggested after the document is stored?

Comment: No, the `_id` is immutable. If you change its value, be it a single or composite, a new document is created.

Comment: So, only when I store I could modify the _id value? Like, in the python code where records are manipulated, _id is added and then stored to DB. Am I correct ?

Comment: No. If you load a document and change the `_id` it is a new document.

Comment: _"There is no such notion as a primary key in MongoDB"_     PK is a part of the data. Based on your example, I would say that MongoDB does have support for a primary key. Since it also supports unique indexes on columns other than _id, I would say it supports Surrogate and Natural keys also.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your Mongo installation is sharded, you can you create a unique compound index on multiple fields and use this as a surrogate composite primary key.

```
db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Alternatively you could create your own `_id` values. However, as the default `ObjectId` is also a timestamp, personally I find it useful for auditing purposes.

Regarding the difference between compound index and composite primary key, by definition primary keys cannot be defined on a missing (null) fields and there can only be one primary key per document. In MongoDB only the `_id` field can be used as a primary key, as it is added by default when missing.  In contrast, a compound index can be applied on missing fields by defining it as `parse` and you can define multiple compound indices on the same document.

Comment: Plz tell me the difference between compound index and composite primary key.

Comment: If you specified a unique index on one or many (compound/composite) fields, and retained the `_id`'s `ObjectId` that would make the `_id` field the surrogate primary key.  The unique index would be a Natural key (would be PK if there was not a surrogate).